# How can I inject an ENV in to all docker containers?

Tags: docker

Is it possible, and how, to inject an env var into all docker containers when they start? For example:

```
$ docker run -it alpine env
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=9816c9031aeb
TERM=xterm
HOME=/root
```

I need it so that an extra, custom env var gets set that doesn't require the docker client to pass with:

```
docker run -it -e MY_VAR=foo alpine
```

The client wouldn't even know what to set even if it wanted to (and, I wouldn't trust them to do so anyways).

I've looked at the `daemon.json` spec and nothing jumps out at me.

Anyone have some ideas?

Comment: `--env-file` flag helps?

Comment: I need to NOT involve the client - that flag is client side